# React JSX Invalid ARIA attribute `ariaLabel`

Tags: reactjs, jsx, accessibility, wai-aria

react jsx:

```
<button ariaLabel='label'>click</button>
```

rendered html:

```
<button arialabel="label">click</button>
```

console warning:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Invalid ARIA attribute `ariaLabel`. Did you mean `aria-label`?
```

ummm no, I meant ariaLabel since we always camelCase in jsx.  Why is it all lowercase in the rendered html?

Comment: just use `<button aria-label`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems to be an exception to the rule. Look at the documentation here -- [Official React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#wai-aria)

> Note that all aria-* HTML attributes are fully supported in JSX. Whereas most DOM properties and attributes in React are camelCased, these attributes should be hyphen-cased (also known as kebab-case, lisp-case, etc) as they are in plain HTML:

Comment: I wish these docs would explain _why_ this is an exception. Does anyone know?

Comment: @jayqui if there hadn't been an exception, React would render `ariaLabel` as `arialabel` instead of `aria-label`. The same rule applies to `data-*`, for example `data-test-id`.